# multiple SOAP-requests in a single server-side transaction

Tags: wcf, web-services, soap, transactions

I'm looking for an out of the box solution to get a server-side only transaction around some SOAP-requests. I'm explicitly not looking for a distributed transaction or WS-* standard, because they change the interface at the client side and I need it to be server side only.

So, for the client:

```
webservice.StartTransaction(); // Or included in DoSomething(...)
webservice.DoSomething(Whatever);
webservice.DoSomethingElse();
webservice.CommitTransaction(); // Or included in DoSomethingElse()
```

At the server, a Transaction must be started at webservice.StartTransaction() and committed at webservice.CommitTransaction. If there is no commit in some limited timeframe, the transaction should rollback.

Comment: This is very unclear. Where are the requests being made from? The server? How was the server code entered? By a request from the client?

Comment: The requests are made from the client: the client does 4 soap calls (the ones in the example). The server must then handle those 4 calls in a single transaction.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "change the interface at the client side". What "interface" are you referring to? Is "StartTransaction" already written?

Answer (score 0):

While your requirements are not entirely clear, you may want to consider leveraging Web Service Coordination (WS-Coordination) along with Web Service Atomic Transaction (WS-AtomicTransaction).

The WS-Coordination specification describes an extensible framework for providing protocols that coordinate the actions of distributed applications. Such coordination protocols are used to support a number of applications, including those that need to reach consistent agreement on the outcome of distributed activities.

http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-tx/wstx-wsat-1.2-spec-os/wstx-wsat-1.2-spec-os.html

The WS-AtomicTransaction specification provides the definition of the Atomic Transaction coordination type that is to be used with the extensible coordination framework described in WS-Coordination. This specification defines three specific agreement coordination protocols for the Atomic Transaction coordination type: completion, volatile two-phase commit, and durable two-phase commit. Developers can use any or all of these protocols when building applications that require consistent agreement on the outcome of short-lived distributed activities that have the all-or-nothing property.

https://www.oasis-open.org/committees/download.php/35161/wstx-wscoor-1%202-spec-os.pdf

A Microsoft-based example:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752261(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Yes, I thought about that, but it involves complicating the client with WS-* standards. I would like the client to do just some elementary soap-calls and do the transactional stuff just in the server, so 'dumb' clients can still have there calls bundled in an atomic transaction. For example a file upload in 2 steps, where in the first step the client sends the metadata (filename, comment, whatever) and the server returns a correlationId and in the second soap call the client sends just the correlationID and the filedata and then the server commits both.